# EventBus function not firing EasyMock

Tags: unit-testing, gwt, easymock

I am newbie to  so this might be a simpler question. Let me ask this one. I am testing my MVP application using EasyMock. I have defined an EventBus. I have mocked some objects. Following is the code:

```
service.getAllBooks(isA(MethodCallback.class));
    expectLastCall().andAnswer(new IAnswer<Object>() {

        @Override
        public Object answer() throws Throwable {
            final Object[] currentArguments = getCurrentArguments();
            MethodCallback callback = ((MethodCallback)currentArguments[1]);

            List<Book> model = new ArrayList<Book>();
            Book modelItem = new Book();
            model.add(modelItem);

            Method method = org.easymock.classextension.EasyMock.createNiceMock(Method.class);
            callback.onSuccess(method, model);
            return null;
        }

    });
```

In success method, I use following code in Presenter

```
public void onSuccess(Method method, List<Book> response) {
                       log.info("Received response.");
            getEventBus().receivedResponse(reponse);
        }
```

Event Bus is following:

```
@Events(startPresenter = ApplicationPresenter.class, ginModules = UiGinClientModule.class)
public interface UiEventBus extends EventBusWithLookup
{

   @Start
   @Event(handlers={ ApplicationPresenter.class })
   void start();

   @Event(handlers={ ApplicationPresenter.class })
   void receivedResponse(List<Book> response);
}
```

I am registering EventBus with ApplicationPresenter in Test class as:

```
   public class ApplicationPresenterTest {
    ApplicationPresenter applicationPresenter;
IApplicationView applicationView;

MyRestService mService;
UiEventBus eventBus;


@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception
{
    applicationView = createStrictMock(IApplicationView.class);
    eventBus = createStrictMock(UiEventBus.class);

    applicationPresenter = new ApplicationPresenter();
            applicationPresenter.setEventBus(eventBus);
    mService = createStrictMock(MyRestService.class);

}
}
```

When I execute the test, I received only log but event bus is not firing event. Is this due to that I am mocking EventBus? If that is the reason, then how to use actual event bus sothat it can fire event.

Thanks,

Comment: could you put some code that show how do you register event bus? and also refer this sample link http://alextretyakov.blogspot.in/2011/11/gwt-event-bus-basics.html.

Comment: Please check the editted post. in setUp(), i am creating mock for EventBus then I am setting event bus in Presenter. Is the procedure corrent?